# Vue.js render v-container only if fullWidth setting is not true

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I have the following structure and I want to include the container only if the website setting is not fullWidth.

For the moment, if I set the fullWidth=false, I am unable to see the HelloWorld component, but I want to see it, only not within a container.

```
<v-content>
  <v-container v-if="!layoutIsFullWidth()">
    <HelloWorld/>
  </v-container>
</v-content>
```

I know this is a stupid question, but I've tried everything, and didn't find a situation similar to it, or I didn't knew what to search.

Thank you!

Comment: please share the code of `layoutIsFullWidth()` method

Comment: If `layoutIsFullWidth` is returning some width/bool then JS is not needed here - use CSS's media querys.

Comment: it is just returning true/false.

export default {
...
  data () {
    return {
      settings: {
        layout: {
          darkTheme: false,
          fullWidth: false
        }
      },
      leftDrawer: {
        activated: true,
        opened: false
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    hasLeftDrawer() {
      return this.leftDrawer.activated;
    },
    layoutIsFullWidth() {
      return this.settings.layout.fullWidth;
    },
    layoutIsDarkTheme() {
      return this.settings.layout.darkTheme;
    }
  }
}
</script>

Comment: @Vucko it's returning only true/false, but i want to not include the container at all if is fullwidth, because I don't need the container.

Comment: @rechim as I said, use CSS here. But if you want a Vue solution, then just remove the braces -> `<v-container v-if="!layoutIsFullWidth">`

Answer (score 0):

As I said, use [CSS for showing/hiding content depending on the window width](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries).

However, if you want a JS/Vue solution, then remove the braces, as it says in your console:

> [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: layoutIsFullWidth is not a function"

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    message: 'Hello Vue.js!',
    settings: {
      layout: {
        darkTheme: false,
        fullWidth: false
      }
    },
    leftDrawer: {
      activated: true,
      opened: false
    }
  },
  methods: {
    hasLeftDrawer() {
      return this.leftDrawer.activated;
    },
    layoutIsFullWidth() {
      return this.settings.layout.fullWidth;
    },
    layoutIsDarkTheme() {
      return this.settings.layout.darkTheme;
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <p v-if="!layoutIsFullWidth">{{ message }}</p>
</div>
```

Also, better use a [computed property](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html) for this purpose:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    message: 'Hello Vue.js!',
    settings: {
      layout: {
        darkTheme: false,
        fullWidth: false
      }
    },
    leftDrawer: {
      activated: true,
      opened: false
    }
  },
  computed: {
    hasLeftDrawer() {
      return this.leftDrawer.activated;
    },
    layoutIsFullWidth() {
      return this.settings.layout.fullWidth;
    },
    layoutIsDarkTheme() {
      return this.settings.layout.darkTheme;
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <p v-if="!layoutIsFullWidth">{{ message }}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I've come up with this solution

<div v-if="!layoutIsFullWidth()">
        <v-container>
          <HelloWorld/>
        </v-container>
      </div>
      <div v-else="!layoutIsFullWidth()">
        <HelloWorld/>
      </div>

but now i got an extra div